# Unitils doesn't work

Tags: testing, unitils

I have a big problem

my unitils.properties:

```
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/timesheet_test
database.userName=root
database.password=
database.schemaNames=timesheet_test
database.dialect=mysql

updateDataBaseSchema.enabled=true
dbMaintainer.script.locations=src/test/resources/dbscripts
dataSetStructureGenerator.xsd.dirName=target/xsd

dbMaintainer.autoCreateExecutedScriptsTable=true
dbMaintainer.disableConstraints.enabled=false

## Módulos do unitils
unitils.module.database.enabled=true
unitils.module.dbunit.enabled=true
unitils.module.hibernate.enabled=true
unitils.module.spring.enabled=true
unitils.module.mock.enabled=false
unitils.module.easymock.enabled=false
unitils.module.inject.enabled=false
unitils.module.jpa.enabled=false

DatabaseModule.Transactional.value.default=rollback
```

my database.sql:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `timesheet_test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `timesheet_test` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `timesheet_test`.`DATA`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `timesheet_test`.`DATA` (
  `ID_DATA` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `DATA` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_DATA`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `data_UNIQUE` (`DATA` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_DIAS_UNIQUE` (`ID_DATA` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `timesheet_test`.`USUARIO`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `timesheet_test`.`USUARIO` (
  `ID_USUARIO` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `E_MAIL` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `SENHA` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
  `NOME` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_USUARIO`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `E_MAIL_UNIQUE` (`E_MAIL` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_USUARIO_UNIQUE` (`ID_USUARIO` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `timesheet_test`.`TIME_SHEET`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `timesheet_test`.`TIME_SHEET` (
  `ID_TIME_SHEET` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `INICIO` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL ,
  `FIM` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL ,
  `LONGITUDE` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `LATITUDE` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `OBSERVACAO` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `ID_DATA` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL ,
  `ID_USUARIO` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_TIME_SHEET`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_TIME_SHEET_UNIQUE` (`ID_TIME_SHEET` ASC) ,
  INDEX `FK9735054D39B29F66` (`ID_DATA` ASC) ,
  INDEX `FK9735054D9DA5550A` (`ID_USUARIO` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `FK9735054D9DA5550A`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USUARIO` )
    REFERENCES `timesheet_test`.`USUARIO` (`ID_USUARIO` ),
  CONSTRAINT `FK9735054D39B29F66`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_DATA` )
    REFERENCES `timesheet_test`.`DATA` (`ID_DATA` ))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

USE `timesheet_test` ;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I have 65 tests and I have problem with 6 and the same error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`timesheet_test`.`time_sheet`, CONSTRAINT `FK9735054D39B29F66` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_DATA`) REFERENCES `DATA` (`ID_DATA`))
```

My test is "search" not "delete" but I think when unitils trying delete row to start new test, have problem.

anybody have idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Solution can be found on: https://sourceforge.net/p/unitils/discussion/570578/thread/38fe5abc/

During a clean-insert, data is first deleted from all tables in reverse order as specified in the data set. After that, the data is inserted in the specified order.
So for your data set

```
    <TIME_SHEET />
    <DATA />
    <USUARIO />
```

it first deletes all records in usuario then data and then time_sheet
since there appears to be FK from time_sheet to data (see exception), it cannot delete the data records before deleting the dependent time_sheet records
Solution: just correct the order in the data set (put data before time sheet)

```
    <DATA />
    <TIME_SHEET />
    <USUARIO />
```