# DbUnit fails to clean-insert: foreign key constraint

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, testng, dbunit

I'm asking and answering this question for future reference, because I think I've found a decent solution to a common problem with DbUnit. I hope it helps out someone, somewhere down the line.

I'm using `DbUnit 2.5.0` and `TestNG 6.8.8`. My use case is for a part of a database which comprises 3 entities. There is a `ServiceUser` which holds a foreign key to both an `Administrable` and a `UserGroup`.

I followed most of the code example from http://city81.blogspot.com/2011/03/testing-jpa-entities-using-dbunit.html

```
public abstract class AbstractDatabaseTest {
    protected EntityManager em; // initialized elsewhere
    private IDatabaseConnection connection;
    private IDataSet dataset;

    @BeforeClass
    private void setupDatabaseResource() throws Exception {
        // using Hibernate
        connection = new DatabaseConnection(((SessionImpl) (em.getDelegate())).connection());
        connection.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, new HsqldbDataTypeFactory());

        // full database export
        IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();

        final String datasetPath = String.format("%s%s", RESOURCE_FOLDER, "Testing.xml");
        FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream(datasetPath));

        FlatXmlDataSetBuilder flatXmlDataSetBuilder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
        flatXmlDataSetBuilder.setColumnSensing(true);
        dataset = flatXmlDataSetBuilder.build(new FileInputStream(datasetPath));
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void cleanDB() throws Exception {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(connection, dataset);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

The result of this is the following `XMLDataSet` (data omitted):

```
<dataset>
  <administrable/>
  <serviceuser/>
  <usergroup/>
</dataset>
```

When `TestNG` executes the `@AfterMethod`, I get the following Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testing_db`.`serviceuser`, CONSTRAINT `FK_gyylcfbhpl2ukqs5rm7sq0uy8` FOREIGN KEY (`userGroup_id`) REFERENCES `usergroup` (`id`))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the `XMLDataSet` I created above does not know the foreign key constraints in the tables, and creates the table list alphabetically. The `CLEAN_INSERT` operation, however, takes the list of tables and traverses it in reverse order, and it requires that foreign key references (here: `ServiceUser.userGroup_id`) be deleted before the referenced entity (here: `UserGroup`).

I found this information through [Unitils doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204060/unitils-doesnt-work) and http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/12868-dbunit-test-fails-mysql-server-hates-me?p=337672#post337672

Some minor digging into the DbUnit documentation led to a corrected approach to creating the dataset, which checks for foreign key dependencies and tries to order the entities appropriately:

```
IDataSet fullDataSet = new FilteredDataSet(new DatabaseSequenceFilter(connection), connection.createDataSet());
```

Result:

```
<dataset>
  <administrable/>
  <usergroup/>
  <serviceuser/>
</dataset>
```

This will `CLEAN_INSERT` correctly.

Disclaimer: I have not come across circular dependencies or self-referencing foreign keys, and I have not tested that this fix can handle them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I don't say anything about a code snippet, and all relevant code is available in either the question or the answer.

Comment: The code IDataSet snippet you were using. In what file did you place that?

Comment: It replaces ``IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();`` in the `@BeforeClass` method

Comment: "The CLEAN_INSERT operation, however, takes the list of tables and traverses it in reverse order" <= life saving answer, thank you so much!